# Не работает кнопка у бота в вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота для группы в контакте.
Начал добавлять кнопки, но они не появляются в сообщениях с ботом. При этом ошибки программа не выдает.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api import VkUpload
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor

keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=False)
keyboard.add_button(label="Кнопка 1", color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

token = 'token'
image = ''


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpull = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
upload = VkUpload(vk_session)


def send_msg(id, msg):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': msg, 'random_id': get_random_id()})

def send_loud_photo(id):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id,  'random_id': get_random_id(), 'attachment': 
    ','.join(attachments)})

def send_photo(id, url):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'attachment': url, 'random_id': 
    get_random_id()})

for event in longpull.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:

        msg = event.text.lower()
        id = event.user_id
        attachments = []
        upload_image = upload.photo_messages(photos=image)[0]
        attachments.append('photo{}_{}'.format(upload_image['owner_id'], upload_image['id']))


        if msg == 'привет':
            send_msg(id, 'Привет')
        elif msg == 'фото1':
            send_photo(id, 'url')
        elif msg == 'фото2':
            send_loud_photo(id)
        elif msg == 'ссылка':
            send_msg(id, r'https://vk.com/id'+str(id))
        else:
            send_msg(id, 'неизвестное собщение')
```

Comment: В вашем коде выделил `keyboard`, нажал `Ctrl+F` и нигде не нашел использование `keyboard`

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна текстовая кнопка, то напишите:

```
import json

def get_button(label, color, payload=''):
    return {
    'action' : {
        'type' : 'text',
        'payload' : json.dumps(payload),
        'label' : label
        },
        'color' : color
    }

keyboard = { 
    'one_time' : True/False #Уберётся ли клавиатура после нажатия на любую из её кнопок
    'buttons' : [ #Кнопки
    #Если кнопка одна - оставьте так. 
    #Если нужно несколько кнопок, то поставьте в конце ",", 
    #если же нужно разделить по столбцам, то при каждом новом столбце,
    #кнопку начала столбца нужно поместить в "[]":
    get_button(label='текст кнопки', color='цвет') 
    [get_button(label='текст кнопки', color='цвет')],
    [get_button(label='текст кнопки', color='цвет')],
    [get_button(label='текст кнопки', color='цвет')],
    [get_button(label='текст кнопки', color='цвет')]
    ]
}

keyboard = json.dumps(keyboard, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
keyboard = str(keyboard.decode('utf-8'))
```

А также измените части функций send() на это:

```
def send_msg(id, msg, keyboard):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': msg, 'keyboard' : keyboard, 'random_id': get_random_id()})
```

Если писать так, то будет проще делать клавиатуры, а также вы всегда будете в курсе, где, что и как.
Также, такие кнопки можно быстро менять по их типу.
Но если не надо - используйте только замену send()